# Using grid with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I will try to explain this the best I can, I'm new to flexbox. I added a flexbox that has a username, age, and distance. Once I was finished and wanted to add "location" under username I ran into a problem. I guess in order to achieve what I want I need to add grids. Can anyone help me with this? The code below is what I have, I added a pic of the grid I need.

[Grid I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xZO7.png)

```
<div class="info_wrapper">
 <div class="info_wrapper_inner"><?php echo $profile->username;?>,</div>
 <div class="info_wrapper_ext">&nbsp;<?php echo $profile->age;?></div> 
 <div class="info_wrapper_distance">34 km</div>
      /*** NNED TO ADD UNDR USERNAME ***/
 <div class="info_wrapper_distance">34 km</div>
     /********/
 </div>

.info_wrapper { display: flex; min-width: 100%; min-width: 0; margin-left: 24px; margin-right: 24px; margin-top: 8px;  } .info_wrapper_inner { font-family: 'neometric_altextra_bold'; font-size: 20px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; } .info_wrapper_ext { order: 2; font-family: 'Neometric Medium'; font-size: 20px; flex-shrink: 0; margin-right: 10px; } .info_wrapper_distance { order: 3; margin-left: auto; flex-shrink: 0; font-size: 13px; padding: 5px 11px !important; margin-top: 10px; background: #ecebeb; border-radius: 35px;  color: #040404; font-family: 'LatoWebBold'; font-style: normal; font-weight: regular; } .info_wrapper_location { color: #948f8f; font-family: 'LatoWeb'; font-style: normal; font-weight: regular; font-size: 16px; }
```

Thanks for any help, hopefully, I explained myself properly.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply. I uploaded two images of what I need, the one with "toronto on" is what I need, the black lines represent the grid layout I need but dont know how to accomplish, thanks again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No need for flexbox. You either use **flex** or **grid** approach.

I don't really know what you're aiming for, but regarding the grid you attached, try this:

```
.info_wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.item2 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```
<div class="info_wrapper">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
</div>
```